# Local equation for a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a (Cartier) divisor $D \in \Gamma(Y, \mathcal{K}_Y^\ast/\mathcal{O}_Y^\ast)$, we can consider its image $D_p$ under the natural map $\Gamma(Y, \mathcal{K}_Y^\ast/\mathcal{O}_Y^\ast) \to (\mathcal{K}_Y^\ast/\mathcal{O}_Y^\ast)_p$.  Given a meromorphic function $f \in \Gamma(U, \mathcal{K}_Y^\ast)$ defined in a neighborhood $U \ni p$, we can consider its image under the composition of natural maps $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{K}_Y^\ast) \xrightarrow {\operatorname{div}} \Gamma(U, \mathcal{K}_Y^\ast/\mathcal{O}_Y^\ast) \to (\mathcal{K}_Y^\ast/\mathcal{O}_Y^\ast)_p$.  (Or equivalently we could consider $f \in \mathcal{K}^\ast_{Y, p}$).

Is the statement "$f$ is a local equation for $D$" the same as "$(\operatorname{div} f)_p = D_p$" here?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Given an arbitrary Cartier divisor $D$, we have that $D$ is locally principal: for every open affine subset $U\subset X$, the closed subscheme $D\cap U\subset U$ is defined by a single equation. In other words, if $U=\textrm{Spec}\,A$, there exists $f\in A$ such that $D\cap U$ is cut out by $f$ inside $U$ (that is, $D\cap U=\textrm{Spec}\,A/fA$). Such an $f$ is called a local equation for $D$.

In your question, you start with a *principal* Cartier divisor $D$. Principal means: belonging to the image of 
$$\textrm{div}:\Gamma(X,\mathcal K^\times)\to \Gamma(X,\mathcal K^\times/\mathcal O^\times).$$
So indeed $D$ has a global (not just local) equation $f\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal K^\times)$, and any of its images $f|_U$ in the groups $\Gamma(U,\mathcal K^\times)$, for $U$ an open subset, is a local equation for $D$ (and trivially satisfies $(\textrm{div}\, f)_P=D_P$ for every $P$ and $U$ as in your question).

Comment: Ah, you're right, I shouldn't have put the word "principal" there because it makes the question silly.

Comment: Not silly, just a very special case :)

Comment: Does it seem to go through without that condition?

Comment: Yes. Is it clear what is meant by "local equation"? In other words, did I answer your question?